# How to convert all frames in movie clip to key frames?

Tags: flash, automation, jsfl, flash-ide

How do you automatically convert all items of Movie Clip (SymbolItem) in the library that uses Classic Tween to key frames?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this *JSFL* script, supported in Adobe Flash Professional CS4 and later

Documentation can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/index.html

```
var document = fl.getDocumentDOM();

var library = document.library;

for (var libraryItemIndex in library.items) {
    var libraryItem = library.items[libraryItemIndex];

    fl.trace(libraryItem.name + " is " + libraryItem.itemType);

    if(libraryItem.itemType == "movie clip") {

        fl.trace(" processing movie clip");

        library.selectItem(libraryItem.name);
        library.editItem(libraryItem.name);

        var timeline = libraryItem.timeline;

        fl.trace(" contains " + timeline.layerCount + " layers");
        fl.trace(" selected layers " + timeline.getSelectedLayers());

        for (var layerIndex in timeline.layers) {
            fl.trace(" trying to select layer " + layerIndex);
            timeline.setSelectedLayers(Number(layerIndex));
            fl.trace(" converting to key frames");
            timeline.convertToKeyframes(0, libraryItem.timeline.frameCount - 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        fl.trace(" ignoring");
    }
}
```

Output will look like this:

[image]

**Note:** watch out for method `timeline.setSelectedLayers()`, cast to `Number` is neccessary